# How to fix Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: exception, input, nullpointerexception, compiler-errors, output

I have this error when I Run the code but no when I Compile it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:221)
at WillinsLaMarkusFileInputOutput.main(WillinsLaMarkusFileInputOutput.java:23)
```

Here is my complete code

```
import java.io.*;

public class WillinsLaMarkusFileInputOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /* open the files */
        // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

        float[] values = new float[10];
        String str = r.readLine();
        int i = 0;
        float sum = 0.0f, avg = 0.0f;
        /* tokenize the string into floats separated by spaces */
        java.util.StringTokenizer tk = new java.util.StringTokenizer(str, " ");
        while (tk.hasMoreElements()) {
            values[i] = Float.valueOf(tk.nextToken()).floatValue();
            /* compute sum */
            sum += values[i];
            i++;
        }

        /* calculate average */
        avg = sum / 10.0f;

        /* write results to output.txt */
        w.write("Sum: " + sum);
        w.newLine();
        w.write("Average: " + avg);
        w.flush();

        /* close the files */
        r.close();
        w.close();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception goes from this line:

```
java.util.StringTokenizer tk = new java.util.StringTokenizer(str, " ");
```

So first let's read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) when this constructor may throw `NullPointerException`:

> `public StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)`
>
> Throws:
>
> `NullPointerException` - if `str` is `null`

Fine. It means that `str` is `null`. The `str` is assigned in this line:

```
String str = r.readLine();
```

Now you should read the documentation when [`r.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) may return `null`:

> Returns:
>
> A `String` containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or `null` if the end of the stream has been reached

So it signals that end of file is reached. As it's the very first attempt to read something from this file it seems that you are reading an empty file.

In general careful documentation reading may greatly help to understand why your program doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that  I am supposed to add some code to the "input.txt." file ? How would that work if the file is a txt and not a java type file ?